# Can we call QnA bot (For Null intents) from Main Dialog or do we need to use dispatcher?

Tags: c#, botframework

Need to call the QnA bot from the Main Dialog whenever the intent is None,
Can we do that or it can be done via dispatcher?

In MainDialog :
I have added like:
AddDialog(new QnABot(userState));   ---  Like this I called other dialogs.

And called in None intent like:
await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(QnABot), cancellationToken);

Can we call QnA bot from MainDialog or using Dispatcher is better option?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of dispatch is to handle routing to multiple LUIS or QnA models. For example, if you have 2 QnA models (one for chitchat like "How are you?" and "Are you human?" and one for actual faq questions like "How do I make an appointment"), and 1 LUIS model, you would umbrella all of this with a dispatch. Deep down, a dispatch is just a fancy LUIS model. It returns a simple model name instead of an actual reply, and you use the reply to call QnA.

For your example, I would use dispatch, yes. 
[image: picture of dispatch model]

Anything that ends up under that 'None' intent is going to return 'none' in my bot logic. Here's how to get the intent from Dispatch:

```
// Check dispatch result
var dispatchResult = await cognitiveModels.DispatchService.RecognizeAsync<DispatchLuis>(dc.Context, CancellationToken.None);
var intent = dispatchResult.TopIntent().intent;
```

And here's how I would use it to call QnA (using the 'None' intent):

```
else if (intent == DispatchLuis.Intent.None)
{
    cognitiveModels.QnAServices.TryGetValue("faq", out var qnaService);
    if (qnaService == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The specified QnA Maker Service could not be found in your Bot Services configuration.");
    }
    else
    {
        var answers = await qnaService.GetAnswersAsync(dc.Context, null, null);                   
        if (answers != null && answers.Count() > 0)
        {
            await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(answers[0].Answer, speak: answers[0].Answer);
        }
        else
        {
            await _responder.ReplyWith(dc.Context, MainResponses.ResponseIds.Confused);
        }
    }
}
```

These examples are all pulled from the [Botframework-Solution's Virtual Assistant Bot](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions). I would also take a look at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for how language understanding works.

As an aside, I would recommend against naming your dialogs "--bot", because in the long run, you're going to confuse yourself.