# How to Call QnA maker from LUIS none intent in C# v4

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I wanted to know if we can call the QnA maker from "None" Intent of LUIS apart from using Dispatcher? --- I'm using latest CoreBot Template in C# V4 to build my bot.
Any code snippets?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure I just answered this for you yesterday here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116584/can-we-call-qna-bot-for-null-intents-from-main-dialog-or-do-we-need-to-use-dis/57190120#57190120

Comment: This is literally a duplicate OF YOUR OWN QUESTION.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably do best to use the [nlp-with-dispatch](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch) sample as your starting point instead of the CoreBot template, as it already has all of the wiring done for LUIS and QnA maker.

If your already have a QnA Maker KB and LUIS dispatch App setup then you will just need to enter the relevant keys in the `appsettings.json` file, otherwise you will have to complete the pre-requisite steps in the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) before being able to run the bot locally.

Once you've got the bot running it is [this block](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/14.nlp-with-dispatch/Bots/DispatchBot.cs#L51-L69) that you're interested in:

```
private async Task DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, string intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    switch (intent)
    {
        case "l_HomeAutomation":
            await ProcessHomeAutomationAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
            break;
        case "l_Weather":
            await ProcessWeatherAsync(turnContext, recognizerResult.Properties["luisResult"] as LuisResult, cancellationToken);
            break;
        case "q_sample-qna":
            await ProcessSampleQnAAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            break;
        default:
            _logger.LogInformation($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}.");
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Dispatch unrecognized intent: {intent}."), cancellationToken);
            break;
    }
}
```

If you've run through the guide then any qna steps should fall through to the `"q_sample-qna"` case. To answer your question you could add a new case statement to handle the "none" intent here then call the `ProcessSampleQnAAsync` method.

As you add more QnA pairs you will have to update your dispatch model using the `refresh` command documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#refreshing-your-dispatch-model), the install instructions for this tool are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/Dispatch#installation).

Comment: @user64870 Please upvote and mark as accepted if my answer helped you in order to help others that come across this in the future. 

Comment: I do but get this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: No worries. :-)